# Laravel get path of saved file from upload

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I have a laravel upload for file (along with other data that is passed to the database) Everything works. But I just can't figure out how to save the path of the file that is saved.

Here is my controller function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    request()->validate([
        'name'              => 'required',
        'logo'              => 'nullable',
        'original_filename' => 'nullable',
    ]);

    //This is where the file uploads?
    if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {
        $request->file('logo')->store('carrier_logo');
        $request->merge([
            'logo'              => '',//TODO: get file location
            'original_filename' => $request->file('logo')->getClientOriginalName(),
        ]);
    }

    Carrier::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('carriers.index')->with('toast', 'Carrier created successfully.');
}
```

The thing I want to achieve:
I want `logo` to fill with something like `carrier_logo/ZbCG0lnDkUiN690KEFpLrNcn2exPTB8mUdFDwAKN.png`

The thing that happened every time I tried to fix it was that it placed the temp path in the database. Which ended up being something in the PHP install directory.

Answer (score 4):

Just assign result to variable:

```
$path = $request->file('logo')->store('carrier_logo');
```

According to [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#storing-files)

Then you can do with `$path` variable whatever you want.

Comment: With that code the path will be `C:\xampp\tmp\phpA9C1.tmp`

Comment: Code above should upload your file to storage/app/carrier_logo
By default it will use your default disk from config/filesystem.php
If not, try to pass disk variable.

Answer (score 0):

just assign the value like this.

```
 $location=base_path('img/'.$filename);
```

and save it in db.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

**For FileName**

```
$fileName = $request->file('test')->getClientOriginalName();
```

**OR**

```
$fileName = $request->user()->id.'.'.$request->file('logo')->getClientOriginalExtension();

$imageDirectory = 'logo_images';

$path = $request->file('logo')->storeAs($imageDirectory, $fileName);
dd($path);
```